# Не удаётся правильно извлечь Date из DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как было указано в заголовке, не получается правильно извлечь Date из переменной DateTime. Вот мой код:

```
internal_pair.Key = "3/31/2001 12:00:00 AM" // Это ключ в Dictionary

IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);
DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(internal_pair.Key.ToString(), culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
cmd.Parameters["@DATE_TRIMESTER"].Value = date;
```

На выходи, в строке

```
cmd.Parameters["@DATE_TRIMESTER"].Value = date;
```

Мы всё равно получаем почему то "3/31/2001 12:00:00 AM", вместо "3/31/2001".

UPDATE 1: Весь код.

```
                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> aliasesAndDatesAndValues = dictionary;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = homer; Database = RealState_RiskEngine; Integrated Security = True;");
                conn.Open();

                string SQLstr = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (ID_ACCOUNT, DATE_TRIMESTER, VALUE)" +
                   "VALUES ('@ID_ACCOUNT', '@DATE_TRIMESTER', '@VALUE')", databaseTable);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_ACCOUNT", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE_TRIMESTER", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VALUE", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);


                foreach (var pair in aliasesAndDatesAndValues)
                {
                    foreach (var internal_pair in (pair.Value)) 
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@ID_ACCOUNT"].Value = pair.Key.ToString();

                        IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);
                        DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(internal_pair.Key.ToString(), culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
                        var date = dateAndTime.Date;
                        cmd.Parameters["@DATE_TRIMESTER"].Value = date;


                        if (internal_pair.Value.Equals(""))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters["@VALUE"].Value = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters["@VALUE"].Value = Int32.Parse(internal_pair.Value);
                        }

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

P.S. Все эти манипуляции нужны, дабы отправить значение в базу данных SQL Server, в поле типа date.

Comment: ```dateAndTime.Date``` имеет тип ```DateTime```, у которого также указано не только дата, но и время, потому когда вы вызываете ```dateAndTime.Date``` - он просто возвращает дату с указанием на начало суток

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но а как тогда извлечь только дату и запихнуть её в базу данных?

Comment: Пробовали такое? ```SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE_TRIMESTER",                System.Data.SqlDbType.Date); parameter.Value = date;```

Comment: То же самое что и раньше, значение не поменялось =( "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Я, кстати, делал практически то же самое.

Comment: SQL запрос покажите

Comment: Добавил выше код.

Comment: Я может пальцем в небо ткну, давно не писал SQL запросы, но для чего тут кавычки? ```'@DATE_TRIMESTER'```. Пробовали их убрать? Вы переменную пытаетесь в текст загнать и потом обратно распарсить?

Comment: Уберите кавычки вокруг `'@DATE_TRIMESTER'`

Comment: @PashaPash Если я верно помню, кавычки для параметров вообще не нужны. То есть автору следует их и для других параметров убрать

Comment: DateTime.ToShortDateString() не пробовали? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Да, действительно, убрал одинарные кавычки и всё заработало! Кавычки стояли в каком то примере из интернета, поэтому они вошли и в мой код.
tym32167  - добавьте своё "пальцем в небо" как ответ, отмечу, собственно, как ответ.

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из дискуссии в комментариях: SQL запросы не требуют заключения параметров в кавычки. Потому для решения проблемы следует поменять

```
string SQLstr = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (ID_ACCOUNT, DATE_TRIMESTER, VALUE)" +
"VALUES ('@ID_ACCOUNT', '@DATE_TRIMESTER', '@VALUE')", databaseTable);
```

на

```
string SQLstr = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (ID_ACCOUNT, DATE_TRIMESTER, VALUE)" +
"VALUES (@ID_ACCOUNT, @DATE_TRIMESTER, @VALUE)", databaseTable);
```